# WAP configuration consistency

Tags: router, network, wireless, capwap, default-gateway

Simple question, are WAPs always configured from the default gateway's web interface? Do you ever have to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are WAPs always configured from the default gateway's web interface?

Normally the "default gateway" (main router) has no relation to the WAPs. WAPs may have a management interface (console, web GUI, ...) of their own, or they're configured by their wireless controller.

Some routers integrate a wireless controller - then you'd configure the WAPs from that router.

Comment: Ah, I see. One more question, what is the typical method of accessing a WAP's management interface if not through the router? Is it just that it would have its own IP address and you would enter it like you would when configuring a router?

Comment: It might, but that depends on the WAP in question. Ideally, you'd have the WAPs in a management VLAN (perhaps of their own) where only your admins are allowed access.